# Loopback API include filters not working as expected

Tags: node.js, api, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have used different models to simplify what I am trying to achieve and to remove clutter, although the theory should be the same as my actual project.

Use the following assumptions: A system can only have one type of speaker and one type of amp.

Say I have the following models:

```
*** System ***
- id
- name
- speakerId
- ampId

*** Speaker ***
- id
- name

*** Amp ***
- id
- name
```

I have added the following to my System.json model file (which i think is correct):

```
"relations": {
    "speakers": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Speaker",
      "foreignKey": "speakerId"
    },
    "amps": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Amp",
      "foreignKey": "ampId"
    }
  },
```

When I start my app and open the API Explorer and go to create a new instance of Speaker or Amp it expects the following:

```
  *** Speaker ***
- id
- name
- speakerId   *** Why is this here??? ***
```

If I change the System.json model file to look like this (which I think is the wrong way to do it):

```
"relations": {
    "speakers": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Speaker",
      "foreignKey": "id"
    },
    "amps": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Amp",
      "foreignKey": "id"
    }
  },
```

Everything looks right in the API explorer. So I add a few speakers and amps, then add a system.

When I add an include filter to the System GET request:

```
{"include":["speakers","amps"]}
```

It includes the speakers and amps but using the System.id as the index for the Speakers and Amps Models instead of System.speakerId and System.ampId. So to ellaborate if the:

```
System.id = 5 
System.speakerId = 1
System.ampId = 3
```

It will include the speaker with an id of 5 and the amp with the id of 5 instead of including the speaker with an id of 1 and the Amp with an id of 3.

I want to be able to list all Systems including their related Speakers and Amps. How can this be done with Loopback. At the minute I am using the above models with in memory DB instead of my usual ones just to test. Any help would be appreciated as I am now at the point of tearing my hair out!

Regards,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation between models is not correct. You need to tell loopbackjs to use [hasMany through relation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations) to get your data.

Your system.json should be changed to

```
"relations": {
"speaker": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "Speaker",
  "foreignKey": "speakerId"
},
"amp": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "Amp",
  "foreignKey": "ampId"
}},
```

And your speakers should be

```
"relations": {
    "amps": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Amp",
      "foreignKey": "speakerId",
      "through": "System"
    },
```

amp.json

```
"relations": {
    "speakers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Speaker",
      "foreignKey": "ampId",
      "through": "System"
    },
```